# rgba effects don't apply when using SASS or CSS Variables

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Hello I know this might be a duplicate question but I've tried everything I was able to find on the internet but nothing works.

following these suggestions in this [link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2251)

both functions rgba() and rgb() don't reflect any changes when using sass or css variables in them.

```
--color: 1,60,255;
// usage
border: 1px solid rgba(var(--color), 0.4);
```

doesn't work

```
border: 1px solid RGBA(var(--color), 0.4);
```

doesn't work either even after capitalizing the letters

```
border: #{'1px solid rgba(var(--color), 0.4)'};
```

sass interpolation doesn't work too

only this one works

```
border: 1px solid RGBA(1, 60, 255, 0.4);
```

but if I want to start using this last solution, I won't be able to use the variables and if something changes I'll have to do so much dummy work.

Comment: typo issue, you have an extra `)` for in the first code and the  second

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake here, but in the code its written one bracket.
I've edited my question

Answer (score -1):

When you use css variables (custom properties) you need to apply them to an element (`:root` if you want to declare them globally). You can't simply declare them in the way you would declare a Sass variable. So in your example it would look something like:

```
:root {
  --color: rgba(1, 60, 255, .4);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid var(--color);
}
```

Comment: nope, that didn't work.
did you mean var(--color)? that doesn't work either.

Comment: Oh, yes. Indeed. Didn't that work? I made this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqeqOL